# Usage of explicit constructor invocation

Tags: java, constructor, this

I am practicing 'this' keyword in constructors. I came to know 'this' will help to invoke constructor explicitly. But what is its use in real time.

Explicit Constructor Invocation.

```
class JBT {

    JBT() {
        this("JBT");
        System.out.println("Inside Constructor without parameter");
    }

    JBT(String str) {
        System.out
                .println("Inside Constructor with String parameter as " + str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JBT obj = new JBT();
    }
}
```

Comment: `But what is its use in real time.` could you clarify what you actually want to know here or what you are struggeling to understand?

Answer (score 1):

In real life, you mostly use it to set default values (like you did in your example) so that you can simplify your classe's interface for the user.

Very often, this is also needed, when a class evolves over time and you add some new features. Consider this:

```
// First version of "Test" class
public class Test {
     public Test(String someParam) {
         ...
     }
}

// use of the class
Test t = new Test("Hello World");  // all is fine
```

Now, at a later date, you want to add a cool new switchable feature to Test, thus you alter the constructor to:

```
public Test(String someParam, boolean useCoolNewFeature)
```

Now, the original client code will not compile anymore, which is **bad**.

However, if you supply your old constructure signature additionally, all will be fine:

```
public Test(String someParam) {
    this(someParam, false); // cool new feature defaults to "off"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` returns a reference to the current instance/object.

> Well, you can use this keyword to call one constructor from another
>   constructor of the same class if you want to call a constructor from
>   base class or super class then you can use super keyword. Calling one
>   constructor from other is called Constructor chaining in Java.

Example:

```
public class ChainingDemo {
   //default constructor of the class
   public ChainingDemo(){
         System.out.println("Default constructor");
   }
   public ChainingDemo(String str){
         this();
         System.out.println("Parametrized constructor with single param");
   }
   public ChainingDemo(String str, int num){
         //It will call the constructor with String argument
         this("Hello"); 
         System.out.println("Parametrized constructor with double args");
   }
   public ChainingDemo(int num1, int num2, int num3){
    // It will call the constructor with (String, integer) arguments
        this("Hello", 2);
        System.out.println("Parametrized constructor with three args");
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
        //Creating an object using Constructor with 3 int arguments
        ChainingDemo obj = new ChainingDemo(5,5,15);
   }
}
```

> Output:

```
Default constructor
Parametrized constructor with single param
Parametrized constructor with double args
Parametrized constructor with three args
```

Answer (score -1):

The output will be:

```
Inside Constructor with String parameter as JBT
Inside Constructor without parameter
```

because `this("JBT")` will invoke constructor with `String` argument